# Listening to a custom event in javascript

Tags: javascript

i was reading an article on the MDN website talking about how to **customise** an events in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events and i was able to create this

```
const evt = new CustomEvent("swipe", {
    detail: {
       color: "red"
     }
});

documet.addEventListener("swipe", e => {
        console.log(e.detail);
    });

document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

But the problem is, the event got triggered immediately, how can i stop this by defining what a `swipe` really is? for example, i want the event to be triggered when someone click on the screen but i still want to use the `swipe` word as it's listener.

Comment: You can add a `click` event listener on the `document` and then dispatch `swipe` event from the click event handler and handle the `swpipe` event in the `swipe` event handler function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...i want the event to be triggered when someone click on the screen...

You'd use a `click` (or `mousedown`) handler to trigger your `swipe` event:

```
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("swipe", {
        detail: {
           color: "red"
         }
    }));
});
```

Live Example:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("swipe", {
        detail: {
           color: "red"
         }
    }));
});

document.addEventListener("swipe", e => {
    console.log(e.detail);
});
```

```html
Click anywhere on the document.
```